# How macro works on google sheet, can't use mine

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this macro to copy a formula value in another column created for me by a guy in this forum

```
/**
* The column B hosts the formulas and the column A hosts the output
*/
function myFunction() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("A1").setValue(ss.getRange("B1").getValue());
}
```

I inserted it as a macro in my google sheet file, I gave the authorization but now I can't figure out how to use it: it's the first time I use macros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Go to `Tools > Script editor`.

   - If not already done - paste your script into the editor.
   - Save the script and run it by clicking on the triangular "Play" button.
2. Go to `Tools > Macros -> Import`.

   - Find your function of interest (`myFunction`) and click on `Add function`
   - Now, to run the macro, go to `Tools > Macros -> myFunction`

For further reading please consult the [Apps Script Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/custom-functions) and [Google Sheets Macros](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros).

Comment: I figured out that I was doing correctly, the problem is I haven't understood how to use properly myFunction. If you understand how it works would you be so gentle to explain me? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by using `myFunction`? The function assigns the content of the cell B1 to the cell A1.

Comment: I'm sorry I found the problem: I'm pretty stupid. In my mind I wanted A1 in B1 and the function does the opposite. sorry for wasting your time